# Properties of measures

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I want to know if the following is true or not. If not please give me an answer what the left side is when computed the integral:

1 Let $\mu$ be the counting measure, then

$$\int 1_{\Omega}(x)\mathrm{d}\mu = \sum1_{\Omega}(x)$$

Edit: It is not an exercise. Just for understanding better.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notation does not make much sense to me. $\Omega$ is a set, $\xi$ a measure and thus $\xi(\Omega)\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\{\xi(\Omega)\}$ contains only one element/number. If $\lambda$ is the Lebenque-measure then $\lambda(\{\xi\Omega\})=0$. Also $\Omega=k$ does not make much sense if $\Omega$ is a set and $k\in\mathbb{R}$.

Edit:
First one is correct, but only for the counting measure. More general case would be
$$\int 1_{\Omega}(x)\mu(dx) = \int 1_{\Omega}d\mu = \mu(\Omega),$$
assuming that $\mu$ is a measure on the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and $\Omega\in\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But if we have the counting measure isn't it
$$\int_{\mathbb{N}}1_{\Omega}d\mu =\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}1_{\Omega}(n) =\mu(\Omega)$$?
So we count how many elements of $\mathbb{N}$ are in $\Omega$?

Comment: Oh, I missed the counting measure... Yes, written like this is correct. But also in this case I would rather write $$\mu(\Omega) = \int_A 1_\Omega d\mu = \sum_{a\in A} 1_\Omega(a)$$
There is no need to restrict ourselves to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thank you for your patience!